# Unable to recover boot partition after encrypting root system

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption, boot-repair

I encrypted my existing NVMe root partition of Xubuntu 22.04.2 LTS using [this guide](https://opencraft.com/tutorial-encrypting-an-existing-root-partition-in-ubuntu-with-dm-crypt-and-luks/).

Now, when trying to boot, I keep being thrown into the GRUB screen.

I have tried **a lot** to repair the bootloader using a live USB stick, e.g.

```bash
sudo cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p2 rootfs
sudo mount /dev/mapper/rootfs /mnt
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /run /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt

# and then multiple iterations and variants of following commands
apt update && apt -y install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64 linux-generic linux-headers-generic
grub-install
# or alternatively
grub-install /dev/nvme0n1

update-grub

update-initramfs -k all -c
```

Sometimes I got into a boot loop which threw me right into BIOS, another time I get into GRUB screen with no idea what to do.

I also tried using boot-repair, however even after opening the encrypted hard drive using `cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p2 rootfs` I keep getting the error message "Encrypted partition detected. Please retry after mounting your encrypted partitions so that the tool can verify their contents. (sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p2 myvolume)".

Here's the boot-repair boot info log: [debian pastezone](http://paste.debian.net/1281209)

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sde.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sde1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sdd: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sdf: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on mapper/rootfs

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GF108 [GeForce GT 440] from NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 20200604, bionic, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1.K0 from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0000,0004,0005,0001,0003
Boot0000* Linux Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,7b7462c4-0e32-437d-a027-aff94aeb7d20,0x800,0xff000)/File(\EFI\SYSTEMD\SYSTEMD-BOOTX64.EFI)
Boot0001  Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0200)..GO..NO........}.T.S.1.2.8.G.M.T.E.1.1.0.S...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.......................................*..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.G.5.8.3.7.9.1.0.2.1........BO..NO..........S.a.n.D.i.s.k. .S.D.8.S.N.A.T.-.1.2.8.G.-.1.0.0.6...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.6.1.6.3.9.2.2.4.0.3.1.1. . . . . . . . ........BO..NO..........S.T.2.0.0.0.D.M.0.0.8.-.2.F.R.1.0.2...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .F.W.2.L.V.4.C.W........BO..NO..........S.T.2.0.0.0.D.M.0.0.8.-.2.F.R.1.0.2...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .F.W.0.L.F.J.Y.A........BO..NO..........T.-.F.O.R.C.E. .1.T.B...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.1.1.0.2.7.0.7.0.2.0.0.5.1.0. .0. . . . ........BO..NO..........W.D.C. .W.D.8.0.E.F.Z.Z.-.6.8.B.T.X.N.0...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . .W. .-.D.A.C.4.1.0.S.K.6........BO
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7b7462c4-0e32-437d-a027-aff94aeb7d20,0x800,0xff000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0003  USB KEY   BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0b00)..GO..NO........a.G.e.n.e.r.a.l. .U.D.i.s.k. .5...0.0...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A................................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L..........BO
Boot0004* UEFI: General UDisk 5.00  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(9,0)/CDROM(1,0x3c4,0x4d00)..BO
Boot0005* UEFI: General UDisk 5.00, Partition 2 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(9,0)/HD(2,MBR,0x2c534026,0x3c4,0x1340)..BO

a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
28da651ee9bfa8571bfc218b7f6cb200   nvme0n1p1/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far
mapper/rootfs   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ng, update-grub,    not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
mapper/rootfs   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
mapper/rootfs   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk identifier: 5345F0EE-F12B-4A70-BC5D-3BA005C516CC
            Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1    2048   1046527   1044480   510M EFI System
nvme0n1p2 1046528 250068991 249022464 118.8G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 523E7DA8-0EF9-40AC-ADDC-51F078BA78EE
      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sda1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T unknown
Disk sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 5FDE81DC-AE93-4E0C-95AA-8D9A61AF30C3
      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sdb1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T unknown
Disk sdc: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk identifier: 60632461-A2BD-4576-A998-2D273971ECB9
      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sdc1   2048 250068991 250066944 119.2G unknown
Disk sdd: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk sde: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: DD8D9E63-1C14-4089-BEE8-831E61525CAE
      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sde1   2048 2000408575 2000406528 953.9G unknown
Disk sdf: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x2c534026
      Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
sdf1  *        0 1802239 1802240  880M  0 Empty
sdf2         964    5891    4928  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
Disk zram0: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram1: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram2: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram3: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram4: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram5: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram6: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram7: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram8: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram9: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram10: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk zram11: 1.3 GiB, 1403592704 bytes, 342674 sectors
Disk mapper/rootfs: 118.8 GiB, 127491112960 bytes, 249006080 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST2000DM008-2FR1:;
1:1049kB:2000GB:2000GB:::;
sdb:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST2000DM008-2FR1:;
1:1049kB:2000GB:2000GB:::;
sdc:128GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA SanDisk SD8SNAT-:;
1:1049kB:128GB:128GB:::;
sdd:8002GB:scsi:512:4096:unknown:ATA WDC WD80EFZZ-68B:;
sde:1024GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA T-FORCE 1TB:;
1:1049kB:1024GB:1024GB:::;
sdf:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:General UDisk:;
2:494kB:3017kB:2523kB:::esp;
mapper/rootfs:127GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (crypt):;
1:0.00B:127GB:127GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:128GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:TS128GMTE110S:;
1:1049kB:536MB:535MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:536MB:128GB:127GB:::;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sdf: 2.88MiB:30000MiB:29997MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE      UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                      
└─sda1      crypto_LUKS f3f66cdb-3f23-4349-8fba-34dcfc4e4cda 84e2d641-cb21-481e-9990-e75d1e4a9ecc                        
sdb                                                                                                                      
└─sdb1      crypto_LUKS 56c3b9f8-c9f3-48a6-be97-b2d95c3da4b2 261ff605-7ed8-4ec3-8a25-94bf267a7a03                        
sdc                                                                                                                      
└─sdc1      crypto_LUKS e0eaa6a9-d2c0-4fcc-8c7e-bba4356ebb25 04171254-527f-4d91-8430-1e28a16f1706                        
sdd         crypto_LUKS 57ebf54e-aa8f-4dc9-9808-a4c1411b61fe                                                             
sde                                                                                                                      
└─sde1      crypto_LUKS 3691525b-fbc5-47c5-9871-918a08cfe6ad 6481d0ff-32ce-4de4-9d29-1e8c61508993                        
sdf         iso9660     2020-06-13-00-42-55-00                                                    Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
├─sdf1      iso9660     2020-06-13-00-42-55-00               2c534026-01                          Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
└─sdf2      vfat        D055-8513                            2c534026-02                          Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
nvme0n1                                                                                                                  
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat        5B2A-905A                            7b7462c4-0e32-437d-a027-aff94aeb7d20                        
└─nvme0n1p2 crypto_LUKS 17264dfd-5a62-4e46-b158-947550fd9d3e 417a1109-5462-4376-8e99-9a1ab230e33b                        
  └─rootfs  ext4        b12717bb-64f6-4a97-ab38-4722a80cece7                                                             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                    Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootfs  64.9G  39% /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/rootfs
/dev/nvme0n1p1     494.5M   3% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/sdf                0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
rootfs

====================== nvme0n1p1/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid b12717bb-64f6-4a97-ab38-4722a80cece7 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

================= nvme0n1p1: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             grub/grub.cfg                                  1

====================== sdf/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =======================

Boot-Repair-Disk session
Boot-Repair-Disk session (failsafe)

==================== sdf: Location of files loaded by Grub =====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================================= User choice ==================================

Is there RAID on this computer? no



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to unsign) and reinstall the grub-efi of
mapper/rootfs,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

 Encrypted partition detected. Please retry after mounting your encrypted partitions so that the tool can verify their contents. (sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p2 myvolume)

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
```

Comment: Not an answer, but an explanation of why you're out of luck. When the system boots, it knows nothing about encryption/decryption. `grub` is trying to find the Ubuntu system to boot, but all it sees is an encrypted mess.

Comment: There's a few possibilities: 1) you didn't follow the procedure correctly; 2) there were errors with one or more of the steps, and you passed over a step or steps without them completing; or 3) the procedure you followed is wrong or outdated. It is a personal blog post from three years ago which is not an authoritative source. In any case, reviewing how many steps it takes to encrypt a system after-the-fact, there's a good reason why it's not a good practice to try to encrypt after installation. I recommend reinstalling, and encrypt during installation, and restore your backups

Comment: @Nmath unfortunately, that's what I ended up doing.